# Prove a sequence converges test.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

> Show that if  $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to \infty } \frac{{{x_{n + 1}}}}{{{x_n}}} = \ell$ and $\left|\ell\right| < 1$ then $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to \infty } {x_n} = 0$

Let 
$\varepsilon  = \frac{{1 - \left|\ell\right|}}{2}$

By definition of limit:

There exists $N_0>1$ such that for all $n\ge N_0$:
$$\left| {\frac{{\left| {{x_{n + 1}}} \right|}}{{\left| {{x_n}} \right|}} - \left|\ell\right|} \right| < \varepsilon $$

Then, for any $n\ge N_0$ we have:

$$\frac{{\left| {{x_{n + 1}}} \right|}}{{\left| {{x_n}} \right|}} < \frac{{\left|\ell\right| + 1}}{2} < 1$$

**This is the part I don't understand:**
In particular, we have for any $n\ge N_0$:

$$\left| {{x_{n + 1}}} \right| < {\left( {\frac{{\left|\ell\right| + 1}}{2}} \right)^{n - {N_0} - 1}}\left| {x{N_0}} \right|$$

The right-hand side converges to $0$ and we're done.

Now, I got two questions:

1. The last inequality is not very clear to me. In particular the power $n-N_0+1$.
2. How could I think of choosing this specific $\varepsilon$? What is the right strategy? This is essential question to me.

Thanks!

Comment: It's the value $|l|+1\over2$ that's important. This is just a number strictly between $|l|$ and $1$ (any such number would do). $\epsilon$ was chosen accordingly so that your second displayed inequality holds. (This seems to me a roundabout way of doing things. )

Comment: As for 1., you have $|x_{n+1}|<C |x_n|<C^2 |x_{n-1}|<C^3|x_{n-2}|<\cdots < C^{n-N_0-1}|x_{N_0}|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for finding the epsilon: we choose the epsilon so that the sequence terms are "close enough" to the limit. Of course, we don't know *a priori* how close do we need them to be. We usually proceed with the proof, and in some crucial place we simply observe what $\varepsilon$ will suffice. For example, here the crucial moment is establishing an upper bound by geometric sequence:

$$
\left|x_n\right|\leq M \left(\left|l\right| + \varepsilon\right)^n
$$
for some constant $M$. What $\varepsilon$ would make it convergent to $0$? Well, any $\varepsilon$ such that $\left|l\right| + \varepsilon < 1$. For example, since $l<1$, $\varepsilon$ such that
$$
\left|l\right|+\varepsilon=\frac{\left|l\right|+1}{2}
$$
is a viable, and quite natural choice.

Comment: Great explanation. Cheers!